# Stop writing blank line at the end of CSV file (using MATLAB)

Tags: matlab, file-io, csv

I'm using MATLAB to open a batch of CSV files containing column headers and data (using the `importdata` function), then I manipulate the data a bit and write the headers and data to new CSV files using the `dlmwrite` function.  I'm using the `-append` and `newline` attributes of `dlmwrite` to add each line of text/data on a new line.

Each of my new CSV files has a blank line at the end, whereas this blank line was not there before when I read in the data ... and I'm not using `newline` on my final call of `dlmwrite`.

Does anyone know how I can keep from writing this blank line to the end of my CSV files?

---

#### EDITED 5/18/10 1:35PM CST

Added information about code and text file per request ... you'll notice after performing the procedure below that there appears to be a carriage return at the end of the last line in the new text file.

Consider a text file named 'textfile.txt' that looks like this:

```
Column1, Column2, Column3, Column4, Column 5
1, 2, 3, 4, 5
1, 2, 3, 4, 5
1, 2, 3, 4, 5
1, 2, 3, 4, 5
1, 2, 3, 4, 5
```

Here's a sample of the code I am using:

```
% import data
importedData = importdata('textfile.txt');

% manipulate data
importedData.data(:,1) = 100;

% store column headers into single comma-delimited
% character array (for easy writing later)
columnHeaders = importedData.textdata{1};
for counter = 2:size(importedData.textdata,2)
    columnHeaders = horzcat(columnHeaders,',',importedData.textdata{counter});
end

% write column headers to new file
dlmwrite('textfile_updated.txt',columnHeaders,'Delimiter','','newline','pc')

% append all but last line of data to new file
for dataCounter = 1:(size(importedData.data,2)-1)
    dlmwrite('textfile_updated.txt',importedData.data(dataCounter,:),'Delimiter',',','newline','pc','-append')
end

% append last line of data to new file, not
% creating new line at end
dlmwrite('textfile_updated.txt',importedData.data(end,:),'Delimiter',',','-append')
```

Comment: Can you show a simple version of your code here with the data we can store as a file to reproduce?

Comment: Hmm, I have no problems with your code. And I would better leave 'newline' option the same for all dlmwrite (and avoid the for-loop). I think the key is - what OS are you using to run the code, and what to view the output file?

Comment: I am using Windows XP to run the code, and Notepad/Wordpad to view the output file.  When I use Wordpad to view the file, there is simply a blank line at the end of the file.  Strangely, when I use Notepad to view the file, there is a blank line at the end of the file, and then there is some unknown ASCII character (a rectangle) at the end of the last line of data.  When I delete the unknown ASCII character, the blank line is also removed.  This makes me think that a carriage return is being inadvertently placed at the end of the file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't specify 'newline' option in DLMWRITE, MATLAB uses UNIX-style end-of-line character (LF, \x0A in hexadecimal code), even on Windows machine. But it does puts the newline anyway.

If you specify 'newline','pc', it put DOS end-of-line character (CRLF, \x0D0A in hexadecimal code).

Notepad understands only DOS end-of-line. Wordpad understands both. At least how it is on my machine.

I would recommend you to be consistent and use the same 'newline' option for all the lines. This way you will also avoid the for-loop. Then try to open the output file in MATLAB editor.

Why you don't want the end-of-line character at all? If this is what you need, use [FPRINTF](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/fprintf.html) function. BUt to do this you have to open the file first with FOPEN. It probably will be better to rewrite the whole code for the output.

Something like this:

```
fid = fopen('textfile_updated.txt','w');
fprintf(fid,'%s\r\n',columnHeaders); %# \r\n for PC end-of-line
fprintf(fid,[repmat('%d,',1,size(importedData.data,2)-1) '%d\r\n'],importedData.data(1:end-1,:)');
fprintf(fid,[repmat('%d,',1,size(importedData.data,2)-1) '%d'],importedData.data(end,:));
fclose(fid);
```

Comment: yuk, you are the man!  Thanks very much for your help ... your answer is perfect.

Comment: @Grant M.: Thanks. Please just don't forget to accept an answer that solves your problem.